# Pandas: date (int) automatically converted to float

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

While I have been working with Pandas DataFrame, the year column (int) has been automatically converted to float. Thus, on a plot there are decimals which I don't need. Figured this happened just when I added a new calculated column with two other columns devived.
I've thought that this may be related to missing values and filled them with no result, however. Cheched for infinite values - again, not the case. So now I cannot convert this to int since python says  "IntCastingNaNError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer" despite just before I've converted all inf to nans and added dropna().

When I change column with pd.to_datetime the plot is not affected and shows decimals for year, still. Same as in the dataframe when unstacked.

Even dt.year does not help and date is still float.

```
d['year']=pd.to_datetime(d['year'], format='%Y')
d['year']=d['year'].dt.year
```

Output:
100               2000.0
101               2001.0
102               2002.0
103               2003.0
104               2004.0
...
17428             2016.0
17429             2017.0
17430             2018.0
17431             2019.0
gdp_per_capita       NaN
Name: year, Length: 4854, dtype: float64

Notice that at the end there is that new calculated columns name for some reason.
Cannot understand why it happens.

```
d=pd.read_csv('/kaggle/input/world-energy-consumption/World Energy Consumption.csv')
d=d.iloc[:, [1, 2, 9, 13, 20, 43, 51, 60, 69, 75, 82, 108, 106, 92, 98, 114, 102, 41-42]]
d=d[d['year']>=2000]
d=d.fillna(method='ffill').fillna(method='bfill')
d.loc['gdp_per_capita']=d['gdp']/d['population']
d.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)
d['year'].dropna
d['year'].astype(int)
d['year']

# the plot
regions=['Asia Pacific', 'CIS', 'World', 'Central America', 'Eastern Africa', 'Europe', 'Europe (other)','North America', 'Other Asia & Pacific', 'Other CIS', 'Other Caribbean',
 'Other Middle East', 'Other Northern Africa', 'Other South America', 'Other Southern Africa',  'South & Central America',
 'South Africa', 'World']

e=d.loc[d['country'].isin(regions)]

e=e.groupby(['country', 'year']).aggregate({'energy_cons_change_pct': 'mean'}).rename(columns={'energy_cons_change_pct': 'arccp'})
e.unstack()
plt.xlim(2000, 2020)
sns.lineplot(x='year', y='arccp', data=e, hue='country')
```

Thank you in advance for any comments/hints!

Comment: `d['year'] = d['year'].astype(int)`

Comment: Hi, thanks! but this is the time when it says: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer. Despite I've addressed this with :   d.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)
d['year'].dropna

Comment: `dropna` is a function, `dropna()`. And you can't drop values only from one column without changing the row. Also, you need to assign the results back, just like in `astype`.

Comment: thank you! I;ve managed to figure out that this was due to the fact that I've added a new columns with .loc which resulted in adding this to the end of the rows and caused an error. But at the plot still I have floats...